# Existence of the derivative of a function at an end point

Tags: calculus

For a function with the rule $f(x)=x^3e^{-2x+1}$, where $x\ge 0$,
I thought that the derivative does not exist at $x=0$.

My friend disagreed with me and told me that the derivative exists at this point.

Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't the derivative exist? This function is differentiable and hence continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Find out $f'(x)$ check that at $x=0$ it is zero (finite) so it ids differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \ne 0$ we have

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \frac{x^2}{e^{2x-1}}.$$

Hence $ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ exists and $=0.$

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I don't think this is totally transparent as written - the notation $\lim x \to 0 f(x)$ typically presumes that $0$ is an interior point of the domain of $f$, and while the expression used to define $f$ has this property, the given definition (with "where $x \ge 0$") requires at least an acknowledgement (as some of the other answerers have given).

Comment: This sense of differentiability would say that $f(x) = 1$ if $x = 0$, $0$ otherwise is differentiable at $0$ despite being discontinuous there.

Answer (score 10):

If you say that $f$ is defined only in $[0, +\infty[$, then $f$ is *right-differentiable* in $0$ because the one-sided limit
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{\color{red}+}} \frac {f(x) - f(0)} {x - 0}$$
exists as a real number.

Comment: It is somehow weird when answers get the "accepted-answer" tag that do NOT answer the question. So, +1 because you clearly state that the question is about right-sided differentiability.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiability is usually defined in the interior of the domain, and $\operatorname{int}([0,\infty))=(0,\infty)$. So strictly speaking, $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Differentiability on an open interval is defined something like this: We call $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable on $(a,b)$ if $\forall x \in (a, b)$, we have that $\exists f'(x)$.

And you can extend this definition to closed, half-closed, etc. sets as well. For example, differentiability on $[a, b)$ is usually defined as follows: $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable on $[a,b)$ if $\forall x \in (a, b)$, we have that $\exists f'(x)$ and $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to a + 0} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

So it's up to your definition if you call it a differentiable function on $[0, \infty)$ or not. But it's not differentiable at $x=0$ in the usual sense, just from the right side.

Answer (score 0):

That exponential stuff is a red herring here.  Let $g$ be any bounded function defined on a neighbourhood of $0$.  Then obviously $f(x):=x^2\cdot g(x)$ is differentiable in $0$ and $f'(0)=0$ as
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=x\cdot g(x).$$